# AVPlayer doesn't play sound on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios-simulator, avplayer

I want to play music from URL with an `AVPlayer` on the iOS Simulator, but it doesn't work :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    Track *selectedTrack = self.tracksByAlbum[indexPath.row];

    NSLog(selectedTrack.preview);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[selectedTrack.preview stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];

    if (!player) {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }

    [player play];
}
```

The url is :

> http://cdn-preview-6.deezer.com/stream/6d180c6b61078f437b04ec21bbe0fb76-3.mp3

I read that I have to enable user interface sounds effects on OS X, but it doesn't change anything...

Comment: And if you use a `NSError` for the parameter?

Comment: @Larme I now try with an AVPlayer, it is not nil but I haven't sound...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using ARC, you'll need to retain the AVAudioPlayer as it sets to nil automatically, which would be a likely reason for no sound. In your header file if you could make sure your self.player's property is set up like this,

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer *player;
```

from within your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` change the AVPlayer code to this

```
self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];

if (!self.player) {
    NSLog(@"Error");
}

[self.player play];
```

I hope this helps